# C# Write listView to txt?

Tags: c#, listview

I have problem with write listView to txt, my code write all columns (first and second) to txt.
I have this code:

```
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("databaseEN.txt"))
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(item.Text);
                for (int i = 1; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(item.SubItems[i].Text);
                }
            }
        }
```

I need write first column not all column to my txt, how change this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delete this lines:

```
for (int i = 1; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
{
    sw.WriteLine(item.SubItems[i].Text);
}
```

EDIT: Extracted from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983553(v=vs.71).aspx

> The Windows Forms ListView control can display additional text, or
>   subitems, for each item in the Details view. **The first column displays
>   the item text, for example an employee number. The second, third, and
>   subsequent columns display the first, second, and subsequent
>   associated subitems.**

Comment: -1. This will prevent all columns from being written, but does not explain how to only write the first column.

Answer (score 1):

A `ListViewItem` contains many [SubItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which you can access from your `item` variable.

```
item.SubItems[0].Text;
```

This will get only the first column. You can also specify a column name as a string.

Comment: You should mark this as answered if that helped you solve your problem.

Comment: this is wrong, the first subitem is the second column. Here is the link that explain it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983553(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It works for me. It looks long because of the coments and the new lines added so it looks good in the text file when it gets saved.

```
// Save File Button
        private void save_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\bbbb.txt", Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

            // Columns NAMES
            for (int c = 0; c < timeTable_listView.Columns.Count; c++)
            {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\bbbb.txt", timeTable_listView.Columns[c].Text+"\t");
            }

            // Add new Line int the txt file
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\bbbb.txt", Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);


            // Get all Items  "loop All items"
            for (int i = 0; i < timeTable_listView.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                // Loop all Sub Items of the Current Item "[i]"
                for (int a = 0; a < timeTable_listView.Items[i].SubItems.Count; a++)
                {
                    // Write the sub item "[a]" to the file with "tab betwen each item"
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\bbbb.txt", timeTable_listView.Items[i].SubItems[a].Text + "\t");
                }

                // Add new Line "the new Row" starts at new line
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\bbbb.txt", Environment.NewLine);
            }

        }
```

[Iamege: Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti6eY.png)

[Image: TXT File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXjKE.png)

ONLY CODE:----------------------------------------------------------------

```
private void save_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\bbbb.txt", Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

            for (int c = 0; c < timeTable_listView.Columns.Count; c++)
            {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\bbbb.txt", timeTable_listView.Columns[c].Text+"\t");
            }

            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\bbbb.txt", Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

            for (int i = 0; i < timeTable_listView.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                for (int a = 0; a < timeTable_listView.Items[i].SubItems.Count; a++)
                {
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\bbbb.txt", timeTable_listView.Items[i].SubItems[a].Text + "\t");
                }
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\bbbb.txt", Environment.NewLine);
            }

        }
```